C# - Change button style between visible, disabled and collapse
I currently have a button with a ICommand that is enabled when CanExecute returns true and disabled when CanExecute returns false. Code looks like this:
<Button
    Command="{Binding CommandEdit}"
    Content="Edit" />

Now I would like to have a third option to also hide the button if it's disabled. But this has to be optional i.e. not all disabled buttons should be hidden and sometimes a button can be disabled for state x and hidden for state y.
My first idea was to add new method to the command called Hidden() and get that in the style but I don't know how to get the command in the style.
<Button
    Command="{Binding CommandEdit}"
    Content="Edit"
    Style="{StaticResource DefaultButton}" />

<Style x:Key="DefaultButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Command.Hidden}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger >
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

If I can't access the command in style, do you have any idea how to differentiate between disabled and hidden?

I was missing the correct relative source. Using Self worked like a charm
    <Button
        Command="{Binding CommandEdit}"
        Content="Edit"
        Style="{StaticResource DefaultButton}" />

    <Style x:Key="DefaultButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource=DefaultButtonStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Command.Hidden, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>


From the UI point of view, (in your task) it doesn't matter whether the command is disabled or not.
Your task is to make the button which is disabled invisible.
For Collapsed it is enough to use the converter which is already in .Net:
<!-- In your resources section of the XAML -->
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

<Button
    Command="{Binding CommandEdit}"
    Content="Edit"
    Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                         Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />

For Hidden or state inversion, you need to use either your own custom converter or set style triggers.

RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} was the solution
